# How to set selected effect when click on any image button same as iphone?

Tags: android

I have one screen with some image buttons and image view. when user click on these buttons or image view i need to show selected effect not replace any image instead of these. only selected dark shade effect on button or imageview same as iphone. How it's possible ?

i have not any selected image source , i checked these code ...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

But here we set another image on pressed event.

Anyone know any property of android to directly set select dark shadow 
effect without image ? 
Please anyone suggest how its possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use `setAlpha` method of `imageView` class to do this.

```
imgView.setAlpha(90);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Thats the link for adding images to show different state of buttons. You create a xml file for this and set this file as the background for the button.

Comment: Thanks for your responce , but my problem is select effect without use any additional images..